# perl: increment variable inside string interpolation

Tags: perl, increment, string-interpolation

Is it possible to use the `++` operator inside a string interpolation?  I've attempted the following:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    print "${i++}. $line\n";
}
```

but I get `Compile error: Can't modify constant item in postincrement (++)`

Comment: Along with what ikegami said in his answer, you can also use `printf()`: `printf("%d. %s\n", $i++, $line);`

Comment: @ikegami's is the way to go, but to directly answer your question "Is it possible to use the ++ operator inside a string interpolation?" here a nasty trick I won't admit I even muttered: `print "@{[ $i++ ] }. $line\n"` (it's similar to @dgw's one, which has been written while I was editing this comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `${\($var++)}` to increment the variable while interpolating it.

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $var = 5 ;

print "Before:     var=$var\n" ;
print "Incremented var=${\($var++)}\n" ;
print "After:      var=$var\n" ;
```

This will print

```
Before:     var=5
Incremented var=6
After:      var=6
```

But I would suggest as mentioned in the comments not to use this code because using `printf` is easier to write and read.

Comment: But why would you want to!?

Comment: can this be done with postincrement? i.e. `print "${\($var++)}\n"`?

Comment: @ewok Yes you can.

Comment: @ikegami can you explain why this is bad?

Comment: Complexity is something one should strive to avoid.

Comment: It is overly complicated ... usually you are better of with using `printf`. But it is technically possible. Thats why I posted this answer.

Comment: @dgw thanks. as this does answer the actual question asked, I'm accepting it, but I would recommend adding a quick note to the top that mentions why this isn't the best option.

Answer (score 6):

Bareword `i` is equivalent to `"i"`, so you are doing `"i"++`.

You want:

```
print($i++, ". $line\n");
```

Simpler:

```
print("$i. $line\n");
++$i;
```

A good way to embed values into a string is `sprintf`/`printf`.

```
printf("%d. %s\n", $i++, $line);
```

---

Note that `use strict` disallows barewords, so you'll also get

```
Bareword "i" not allowed while "strict subs" in use
```

That error oddly comes after the error you mentioned.

Comment: what about with `use strict;`?  I have that set.

Comment: @ewok With `use strict`, bareword `i` is an error regardless of `++` or not.

Comment: @ewok, Adjusted wording.